# Ubuntu 18.04, Suspend doesn't work until I press a button, or login

Tags: suspend

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm having this issue where, if I have the power setting to suspend after X minutes of idle, the computer will not turn off at that time. Instead, I have to press a key, and then power goes off.

Perhaps more interesting, if I try to manually suspend the computer, it simply takes me to the login screen. Then, when I login, it performs the suspend.

This is very annoying and I'm trying to figure out why this is happening.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I did manage to address this issue partially by turning off lock-on-suspend, wtih the following command: "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false".
Now, the suspend seems to be working after X minutes of idle. And when I manually try to suspend the computer, it will sometimes suspend after a minute or so, if I don't touch anything.

Comment: Also have this issue, at least for the manuall suspend. Sometimes I leave it and try to log in the next morning and open an app, where it suddenly suspend on me and I realize it's been running the whole night.